# Add product category to post_class

Tags: categories, plugins

In the content-product.php template, this is the section of the code I am working with (line 43):

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
```

I need to find a way to include categories as part of the $classes variable, because as of now, it is not echoing the categories into the class, and I need this to do a sort on the products. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but adapting from the [Codex example for filtering the post class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters)... basically changing `get_the_categories()` to `get_the_terms` and accounting for the name of the Product Category taxonomy.

```
// add category nicenames to post class
function product_category_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    foreach((get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat')) as $term)
        $classes[] = $term->name;
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'product_category_class');
```

Comment: That actually did work for the first instance, but none of the others; it's throwing this php error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare product_category_class() (previously declared in /Users/KBD/Desktop/sites/snap-dolls/wp-content/themes/snap-dolls/woocommerce/content-product.php:40) in /Users/KBD/Desktop/sites/snap-dolls/wp-content/themes/snap-dolls/woocommerce/content-product.php on line 45

Comment: I moved it to my functions (where it should have been anyway) and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, this belongs in functions.php.  You can never have two functions with the same name in PHP, or you will get the error that you saw.